# How to save more than one record using django forms

Tags: python, django

I have a simple form, this is a part of my view code:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = testForm( request.POST )
    if form.is_valid():
        record = form.save(commit=False)
        record.save()
```

Everything works great, the tools saves data, but I am trying to send more than one record, I mean I am sending for an instance 10 records, but program can save only one.

what is the best solution to solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Your example code attempts to create only a single record. Can you post the code that creates 10 but doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

**Sending 10 records will not create 10 records for you.** The code you've given only attempts to:

1. Create one bounded form instance.
2. Validate and Save only only model instance.

You have to loop **n-number of times** to create **n-bounded form/model instances.**

First: Send a data in your POST request in a nice way so that you can separate it inside your views correctly. A **list of dictionaries** could be good choice. Something like:

[   {'Field1': 'some_value' , 'Field2': 'some_value', ... },

{'Field1': 'some_value' , 'Field2': 'some_value', ... },

{'Field1': 'some_value' , 'Field2': 'some_value', ... }   ...]

Now inside your views.py, loop through this list like:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    for single_data_instance in request.POST:
        form = testForm(single_data_instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            record = form.save(commit=False)
            record.save()
```

**EDIT:**

If you want something apart from a classic for-loop then,

1. There is [django's bulk_create() function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create). But I must warn you that has a number of caveats. You can see all of them in the link given above.

   But, sadly the functionality of `bulk_create()` is not extended to ModelForms yet. You will have to make some changes with it's `save()` method which will be a big overhead.
2. You can also use a lambda function but it'll only make things more cumbersome in this case.

So in my humble opinion, why not just use a classic for loop?

**Lastly,** It doesn't matter if the `name` attribute of your html is the same. As in:

```
<input type="text" name="test">
<input type="text" name="test">
```

A bound form can only take as much fields that are defined(explicit declaration or through ModelForm Meta declaration) inside it. Sending a dictionary with more than what can be taken by a form is of no use. It'll simply ignore it.

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Comment: hey,You didn't understand me, but thanks for your message

Comment: for example, I have such inputs:

Comment: <input type="text" name="test"> <input type="text" name="test"> <input type="text" name="test">

Comment: So as you see there are 3 inputs with the same name attr

Comment: I know I can use simple for loop

Comment: but I would like what is the best solution for django

Comment: @python_beg2 , since a for-loop wasn't given in the code snippet inside the question, I wrote about using a for-loop in my original answer. Anyways, I found some other methods. Please check them out; I've updated my answer.